# How to access all textfields in a row of the TextfieldCellFactory

Tags: javafx, tableview, textarea

I'm using a listener to set the height of my Textarea in the TextfieldCellFactory:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Supermain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final TableView<myTextRow> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setStyle("-fx-text-wrap: true;");

        //Table columns
        TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmID = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        clmID.setMinWidth(160);
        clmID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));

        TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmtext = new TableColumn<>("Text");
        clmtext.setMinWidth(160);
        clmtext.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text"));
        clmtext.setCellFactory(new TextFieldCellFactory());

        TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmtext2 = new TableColumn<>("Text2");
        clmtext2.setMinWidth(160);
        clmtext2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text2"));
        clmtext2.setCellFactory(new TextFieldCellFactory());

        //Add data
        final ObservableList<myTextRow> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new myTextRow(5, "Lorem","Test"),
                new myTextRow(2, "Ipsum","Test2")
        );

        table.getColumns().addAll(clmID, clmtext,clmtext2);
        table.setItems(data);

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(5.0);
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Get Data");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                for (myTextRow data1 : data) {
                    System.out.println("data:" + data1.getText());
                }
            }
        });

        hBox.getChildren().add(btn);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setTop(hBox);
        pane.setCenter(table);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 640, 480));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    public static class TextFieldCellFactory
            implements Callback<TableColumn<myTextRow, String>, TableCell<myTextRow, String>> {

        @Override
        public TableCell<myTextRow, String> call(TableColumn<myTextRow, String> param) {
            TextFieldCell textFieldCell = new TextFieldCell();
            return textFieldCell;
        }

        public static class TextFieldCell extends TableCell<myTextRow, String> {

            private TextArea textField;
            private StringProperty boundToCurrently = null;

            public TextFieldCell() {

                textField = new TextArea();
                textField.setWrapText(true);
                textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);

                this.setGraphic(textField);
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty) {
                    // Show the Text Field
                    this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

                    // Retrieve the actual String Property that should be bound to the TextField
                    // If the TextField is currently bound to a different StringProperty
                    // Unbind the old property and rebind to the new one
                    ObservableValue<String> ov = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
                    SimpleStringProperty sp = (SimpleStringProperty) ov;

                    if (this.boundToCurrently == null) {
                        this.boundToCurrently = sp;
                        this.textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(sp);
                    } else if (this.boundToCurrently != sp) {
                        this.textField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(this.boundToCurrently);
                        this.boundToCurrently = sp;
                        this.textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(this.boundToCurrently);
                    }

                    double height = real_lines_height(textField.getText(), this.getWidth(), 30, 22);
                    textField.setPrefHeight(height);
                    textField.setMaxHeight(height);
                    // if height bigger than the biggest height in the row
                    //-> change all heights of the row(textfields ()typeof textarea) to this height
                    // else leave the height as it is


                    //System.out.println("item=" + item + " ObservableValue<String>=" + ov.getValue());
                    //this.textField.setText(item);  // No longer need this!!!
                } else {
                    this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public class myTextRow {

        private final SimpleIntegerProperty ID;

        private final SimpleStringProperty text;
        private final SimpleStringProperty text2;

        public myTextRow(int ID, String text,String text2) {

            this.ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(ID);
            this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(text);
            this.text2 = new SimpleStringProperty(text2);


        }

        public void setID(int id) {
            this.ID.set(id);
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text.set(text);
        }

        public void setText2(String text) {
            this.text2.set(text);
        }

        public int getID() {
            return ID.get();
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text.get();
        }

        public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text;

        }

        public String getText2() {
            return text2.get();
        }

        public StringProperty text2Property() {
        return text2;

        }

    public IntegerProperty IDProperty() {
        return ID;
    }
    }

    private static double real_lines_height(String s, double width, double heightCorrector, double widthCorrector) {
        HBox h = new HBox();
        Label l = new Label("Text");
        h.getChildren().add(l);
        Scene sc = new Scene(h);
        l.applyCss();
        double line_height = l.prefHeight(-1);

        int new_lines = s.replaceAll("[^\r\n|\r|\n]", "").length();
        //  System.out.println("new lines= "+new_lines);
        String[] lines = s.split("\r\n|\r|\n");
        //  System.out.println("line count func= "+ lines.length);
        int count = 0;
        //double rest=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            double text_width = get_text_width(lines[i]);
            double plus_lines = Math.ceil(text_width / (width - widthCorrector));
            if (plus_lines > 1) {
                count += plus_lines;
                //rest+= (text_width / (width-widthCorrector)) - plus_lines;
            } else {
                count += 1;
            }

        }
        //count+=(int) Math.ceil(rest);
        count += new_lines - lines.length;

        return count * line_height + heightCorrector;
    }

    private static double get_text_width(String s) {
        HBox h = new HBox();
        Label l = new Label(s);
        l.setWrapText(false);
        h.getChildren().add(l);
        Scene sc = new Scene(h);
        l.applyCss();
        // System.out.println("dubbyloop.FXMLDocumentController.get_text_width(): "+l.prefWidth(-1));
        return l.prefWidth(-1);

    }
}
```

How can I achieve to read the heights from all Textareas in a row, to compare them and set to the biggest one?

I now add the full code, then it is maybe more clear what I mean.

Comment: What about `textField.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE)`?

Comment: yes,this actually works fine :) But i really need to get access to all textfields in a row because i also want to do some Css styling when clicked or double clicked and some other stuff.